# JsonView in Spring + Kotlin

Tags: spring, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

Server returns empty json with JsonView:

```
[ { }, { } ]
```

I use only `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` bean to configure `jackson`:

```
@Bean
open fun objectMapperBuilder() = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
    .modulesToInstall(KotlinModule())
    .propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
    .featuresToEnable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS)
```

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/drivers")
class DriversController @Autowired constructor(val driverService: DriverService) {

    @JsonView(Views.Public::class)
    @RequestMapping("/nearest")
    fun nearest(): List<Driver> {
        val drivers = driverService.findNearest(49.437551, 32.025263)

        return drivers
    }
```

**Driver table entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ct_drivers")
data class Driver(

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Int = 0,

    @JsonView(Views.Public::class)
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    var firstName: String = "",

    @JsonView(Views.Public::class)
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    var lastName: String = "",

    @Column(name = "phone")
    var phone: String = ""

)
```

**Views object:**

```
object Views {
    interface Public {}
}
```

Dependencies list:

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
compile 'org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-messaging'
compile 'org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.5.RELEASE'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-tx'
compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm:4.2.5.RELEASE'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.0.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.1.0.Final'
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial:5.1.0.Final'
compile 'com.corundumstudio.socketio:netty-socketio:1.7.8'
compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
compile 'com.github.salomonbrys.kotson:kotson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.7.3'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.3'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.3'
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:${kotlinVersion}"
```

How to configure `JsonView` correctly in my case? May be I forgot something?

Comment: Not sure is this can help, but i see often that JsonView uses classes, instead of interfaces. Please, try to create `class SampleView` and use it. Maybe it would help.

Comment: I tried. Same problem

Comment: Try to replace `data class` with class written in java, i think there are problem with annotations on data class properties.

Comment: Maybe you've [faced this issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13331)?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem until I added the following dependency:

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin'
```