# Why does Kotlin with Spring MVC JSON return an empty object?

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, kotlin

I've been playing with server side Kotlin, Spring MVC and Jackson. 
I built a simple application using http://start.spring.io/, but I might have made a mistake in the `JsonView` annotation.

This:

```
@RestController

class MyRestController {
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    @JsonView(User::class)
    fun getUser() : User = User("Fred",50)
}

data class User(val name: String, val age: Int)
```

...when called with curl

```
ph@sleek ~ $ curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/user; echo
{}
ph@sleek ~ $
```

...the result is `{}` when I expected `{"name":"Fred","age":50}`. Is there something I did wrong?

Comment: You need to annotate your data class with `JsonView` as well to tell which properties will be included in which view.

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler than I thought. After finding that Jackson was able to serialise the object just fine, I started making adjustments, and found the default was better than configuration:

```
class MyRestController {
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    fun getUser() : User = User("Fred",50)
}
```

Perfect:

```
ph@sleek ~ $ curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/user; echo
{"name":"Fred","age":50}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you do want to use `@JsonView` (which is necessary in many scenarios), I was running into the same empty object problem until I added the `jackson-module-kotlin` dependency to my project.

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin'
```

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48019143/5258628